# How to restore icons?

Tags: finder, icon

I use TeXShop for TeX/LaTeX, and all the files with tex extension exhibit the TeXShop icon. Some false move had the result that all .tex files exhibit the Excalibur icon. I have used the Info window to reverse this move, using the "Use this application to open all similar files" command (I guess this is the English phrase, my Mac speaks French), but not all the .tex files show a TexShop Icon. Some of them have a blank icon. What can be done to revert to the original and correct behavior of the finder ?

Comment: What happens if you double-click one of the .tex files with the blank icon?

Comment: or if you jut click once?  I had a similar problem but when I single clicked on a name with  default icon its new icon would appear and stay.